# Create rule with array (in Outlook)

Tags: vba, email, outlook

When I receive e-mail I need check mail body. And I have keywords-more than thousand- If mail has that words, rules should be move to a specific folder. I use this script:

```
CreateRule()
    Dim colRules As Outlook.rules
    Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
    Dim colRuleActions As Outlook.RuleActions
    Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction
    Dim oFromCondition As Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition
    Dim oExceptSubject As Outlook.TextRuleCondition
    Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder
    Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("test").Folders("subTest")
     
      Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
    Set oRule = colRules.Create("ruleTest", olRuleReceive)

    Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
    With oMoveRuleAction
        .Enabled = True
        .Folder = oMoveTarget
    End With
 
    Set oExceptSubject = _
        oRule.Conditions.BodyOrSubject
    With oExceptSubject
        .Enabled = True
        .Text = Array("my keywords")
    End with

colRules.Save
End Sub
```

But this script dont accept all my keywords, how can I add them in rule...

Comment: *"this script dont accept all my keywords"* is no useful error description. Please provide a [mcve] with examples for which keywords work and which produce an error. Also include which error message you get and in which line. If there is no error describe what happens versus what you expected to happen.

Comment: I cant write my keywords in here because data security. But i can describe, its personal IDs. I can define array, and append all items , not problem. When i run colRules.save  line it says. "Run-time error '-2147352567 (800200009)': You cannot add another rule because you have exceeded the maximum number of rules for this repository."

Comment: Well there you have it. Your error message is clear: You have to many rules obviously you hit the limit of maximum rules. So that's your issue and there is probably no workaround. You cannot add more rules than allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the array with commas as the following sample shows:

```
'Add the subjects to the rule condition
    For Each objRuleCondition In objSpecificRule.Conditions
        If objRuleCondition.ConditionType = olConditionSubject Then
           If objRuleCondition.Enabled = True Then
              Set objTextRuleCondition = objRuleCondition
              strTextArray = objTextRuleCondition.Text
              varSubjects = objDictionary.Keys
  
              varNewTextArray = Split(Join(strTextArray, ",") & "," & Join(varSubjects, ","), ",")
 
              objTextRuleCondition.Text = varNewTextArray
           End If
        End If
    Next
```

See [How to Quickly Add the Subjects of Multiple Emails to the Condition of a Specific Outlook Rule](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/how-to-quickly-add-the-subjects-of-multiple-emails-to-the-condition-of-a-specific-outlook-rule/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I have docx file, it has all my keywords. How can i import it in this script? Will i give any path?

Comment: You need to read the content of the file and then specify the string with commas like shown in the sample code posted. To read the docx content you can automate Word from your VBA macro.